# Hide empty row in combobox with C#

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I load data into combobox named `cbxTravail`. I have these lines that work fine but my problem is that I have some blank lines that I want to hide them or delete them from the list in combobox.

```
string myconnstrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrng"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

try
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select TeethWorkID,Travail from TeethWorkNamesTable group by TeethWorkID, Travail", conn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    // ds.Tables.Clear();
    // adapter.Fill(ds);
    cbxTravail.DisplayMember = "Travail";
    cbxTravail.ValueMember = "TeethWorkID";
    cbxTravail.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    for (int i = cbxTravail.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i += -1)
    {
        if (cbxTravail.GetItemText(cbxTravail.Items[i]) == string.Empty)
        {
            cbxTravail.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Exception Message
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

I add this line for delete blank items from list but it doesn't work.

```
for (int i = cbxTravail.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i += -1)
{
    if (cbxTravail.GetItemText(cbxTravail.Items[i]) == string.Empty)
    {
        cbxTravail.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Make a separate list of items.  The fill combobox from list : cbxTravail.Items.AddRange(filteredList);

Comment: It would be much better if you could skip those lines by using a `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` statement .... something like `WHERE Travail IS NOT NULL` or `WHERE Travail <> ''` or something like that, to avoid even returning those "empty" lines in the first place

Comment: Thankyou so much i change the SELECT statement to this : "Select * FROM TeethWorkNamesTable WHERE Travail <> '' "  . work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbxTravail.GetItemText(cbxTravail.Items[i]).Trim()))
{
     cbxTravail.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but still dosn't change

Comment: Can you try `.Trim()`. And also what values you have in DB. Can you share that too

Comment: Thank you. problem resolved. i change this line  and now it's work fine
 "Select * FROM TeethWorkNamesTable WHERE Travail <> '' "

Comment: Ok. Good. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
cbxTravail.Items.Remove(String.Empty)
```

This line works for me.